# manually delete solr backup directories

Tags: solr

I make nightly backups of my solr core, but I cannot find any documentation on whether or not I can safely delete older folders that I don't need anymore.  If I delete, for example, all of the folders from `snapshot.201609xx`, will it screw up solr?

[image: filefolder]

Comment: how are you creating these backups ?

Comment: I have a python script that executes each night at 7:30pm that executes this url - `url.com:8983/solr/core/replication?command=backup&name=11162016`